# How to pass gestures from UITextView to UICollectionViewCell

Tags: ios, uitextview, uicollectionviewcell

I have a horizontal scrolling UICollectionView with UICollectionViewCells that contain a UITextView. Is there any way to pass gestures on the textview to the cells, so that  didSelectItemAtIndexPath gets called?.
I tried it with subclassing UITextView and passing touchesbegin/end to the cell, but that didn't worked.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can make the view non-interactive, which will cause touches to get passed through:

```
textView.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
```

If you need it to be interactive, you can try this:

```
textView.editable = NO;
UITapGestureRecognizer* tap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(tapped)];
[textView addGestureRecognizer:tap];
```

... and then add this function to your `UICollectionViewCell` subclass:

```
-(void) tapped {
    UICollectionView *collectionView = (UICollectionView*)self.superview;
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [collectionView indexPathForCell:self];
   [collectionView.delegate collectionView:collectionView didSelectItemAtIndexPath:indexPath];
}
```

I haven't tested it though...

Comment: yeah, but then i can't scroll.

Comment: problem here is that selectItemAtIndexPath:animated:scrollPosition:  does not cause any selection-related delegate methods to be called

Comment: but [cv.delegate collectionView:cv didSelectItemAtIndexPath:ip]; does

Comment: First part of answer works perfectly on  iOS 8 if you don't need interaction.

Answer (score 0):

Well, if your cell is the superview of the text view, you could implement something like this in the `UITextViewDelegate` method `textViewDidBeginEditing:`.

```
- (void)textViewDidBeginEditing:(UITextView *)textView {
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.collectionView indexPathForCell:(UICollectionViewCell *)textView.superview];
    [self.collectionView selectItemAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES scrollPosition:UICollectionViewScrollPositionTop];
}
```

Comment: textViewDidBeginEditing only gets called if the text is getting edited, but i don't wont the text to be editable.

Comment: This does not work for me. I get nil for the indexPathForCell. I can get the cell, just not the indexPath.

Comment: @Micah Sorry about that, I'm assuming you're using iOS 7? The view hierarchy has changed and the cell now exists at view.superview.superview. If you want a more dynamic solution, see my post here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18255361/716216

Comment: Boom! @user716216 thanks! That saved me. Been on this for the past few hours.

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't seem to work in iOS6.x: the all view in a UICollectionViewCell seem to be embedded in a UIView that is the first child of the cell.  In order to get the actual cell that is the UITextView is in you will need to dereference a second time. In other words the order is (from bottom to top):

UITextView->enclosingUIView->UICollectionViewCell