# Redirecting tap behavior to another layer in a UICollectionViewCell

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I am trying to figure out how to change the view in a `UICollectionViewCell` that triggers the `UICollectionView`'s `didSelectCellAtIndexPath`. I want to have a top layer that can be tapped to activate, or panned to reveal a lower layer of buttons.

I can add a view on top, and achieve the pan to reveal gesture, but I have to tap the underlying view to trigger `didSelect`.

Also, I am not using xib's or storyboards, this is all in code.

Any Ideas?

Comment: take a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15681765/how-to-pass-gestures-from-uitextview-to-uicollectionviewcell

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @peko, I figured it out.

```
- (void)selectCell {
    UICollectionView *collectionView = (UICollectionView *)self.superview;
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [collectionView indexPathForCell:self];
    [collectionView.delegate collectionView:collectionView didSelectItemAtIndexPath:indexPath];
}
```

This allows me to simulate selection of the cell from within the view controller.